# Chained select only show second box if can be populated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a chained select which works fine but not all the values in SELECT 1 result in values in SELECT 2 so I would like to hide SELECT 2 unless it has something to show.

I am using this for my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".select1").change(function() {
            var id=$(this).val();
            var dataString = 'id='+ id;
            $.ajax ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_load.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $(".select2").html(html);
                } 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and then I have set my second select to display:none so how can I make it so the second select appears and disappears depending on the value in box 1?

Thanks

Comment: I assume your AJAX return is simply empty if there are no options to display? So check the content of your callback parameter `html` and act accordingly …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".select2").hide();
        $(".select1").change(function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            var dataString = 'id=' + id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_load.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $(".select2").hide();
                }
                success: function (html) {
                    $(".select2").show();
                    $(".select2").html(html);
                   var length = $('.select2 > option').length;
                   if(length>0){
                       $(".select2").show();
                   }else{
                       $(".select2").hide();
                   } 
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick - have to figure out how to make it work when editing/onload as well but hopefully this has me on the right track!

Comment: Struggling to get this work on a form where I am editing so the select1 is populated and the select2 box may or may not be populated depending on the value in select1 - I think I need something based around onload but without losing the onchange as if they choose to change then it should still work as it currently does

Comment: For that you should take one hidden field in php file and the value of that field must be record id which is going to be edited and checked in jquery like:if($("#HIDDEN_FIELD_ID").val()!=""){$(".select2").show()}

Answer (score 1):

/** Whenever changes happens in Select 1 hide Select 2. show select 2only if it has value **/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".select1").change(function() {
                var id=$(this).val();
                var dataString = 'id='+ id;
                $.ajax ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax_load.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                        $(".select2").show();
                        $(".select2").html(html);
                    },
                    error : function() { $(".select2").hide();  }
                });
                var select2Length = $('.select2> option').length;
                if(select2Length > 0)
                  $(".select2").hide();
                else
                  $(".select2").show()
            });
        });
```